Error al conectarme con mi JDBC
ando haciendo un CRUD en java. Es interesante que en anteriores proyecto, e estado ocupado JDBC para la conexion de base de datos y no había tenido ningun problema relacionado con la conexion. Y con el proyecto que ando realizando, cree una clase aparte llamada Conexion.java con el siguiente codigo (Se que tiene datos sencibles sobre la base de datos, pero como es pequeña, no tengo mucho problema en mostrar):
import java.sql.*;

public class Conexion {
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/biblioteca";
    private static final String JDBC_USERNAME = "biblio";
    private static final String JDBC_PASSWORD = "123";

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USERNAME, JDBC_PASSWORD);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al cargar el controlador: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error de SQL: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }
}

Cuando lo compilo junto a mis otras clases, se compilan correctamente, pero cuando ando utilizando el programa y trato de hacer una consulta, me manda el error de que no encontró el controlador de JDBC, busque en muchas partes sobre este error, y me decían que descargara mysql connector, y lo hice con la version 8.4.0, cuando lo agrego en Java Proyects / Referenced Libraries, ahi es donde agrege el JAR de mysqlconnector, pero me sigue mostrando el mismo error. Ya le pregunte a varias personas, hasta mi profesor, y dice el que nunca a ocupado Visual studio, y pues x xd.
Intente de todo, primero agregue el JAR al proyecto, luego lo puse en documentos y desde ahi lo llamo, ya modifique el Código de conexión muchas veces, de diferentes formas, variables etc.
Error que me marca la consola:
>java Ventana.java  
                                   
Error al cargar el controlador: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.close()" because "<parameter1>" is null
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "<local2>" is null
        at DAO.dameUsuarios(DAO.java:15)
        at UsuariosVentana$2.actionPerformed(Ventana.java:65)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6621)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6386)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4996)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)


Dónde incluiste la conexión JDBC para que la librería sql la use?

Te está diciendo que no encuentra la clase com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, tienes que añadirla al classpath al ejecutar el programa
